# Laravel connection to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, database-connection, laravel-5

I installed  the package in https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8 with success,
 and I added  `Yajra\Oci8\Oci8ServiceProvider::class` in my providers.

I ran the command : `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=oracle` and it  created the `oracle.php` file.

In the config  I changed `mysql` to `oracle` in my database.
When I try to put this code in my routes file:

```
Route::get('test', function() { dd (DB::connection()->getPdo()); });
```

I get this error:

> error Call to undefined function Yajra\Pdo\oci_connect()

Comment: You don't have the oci8 package installed on your server, which is required.

Comment: No i enabled it on Wamp Server